# How to achieve Inter Blockchain Communication (IBC)

Tags: mainnet, private-blockchain, http

I've been reading a couple of articles about IBC using EOS like [this one](https://steemit.com/eos/@dan/inter-blockchain-communication-via-merkle-proofs-with-eos-io). The problem is I don't know how to achieve this since most articles don't provide specific information.

I wanna know if I can call actions on the mainnet from a contract on a private blockchain. If not, how about using HTTP calls from the private blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard implementation yet. You can refer to how BOS (another chain based on EOSIO) does this. [[link](https://github.com/boscore?q=ibc&type=&language=)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, this is what we at LiquidApps specialize in.  IBC is see being obtained through 2 categories:

1. Centralized backend
2. Decentralized using msig or otherwise

Both basically work the same way, a nodejs script listens to a table on the opposing chain for new actions, waits for finality, then pushes the action on the opposing chain.

You can read up on our bridges here (EOSIO <> EOSIO & EOSIO <> EVM) https://liquidapps.gitbook.io/liquidapps-documentation/cross-chain-bridges/getting-started-with-liquidbridge

Example bridges here: https://liquidapps.gitbook.io/liquidapps-documentation/introduction/cross-chain-bridge#production-bridges